# Agent admitted failure to sign using the key. OSX

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, osx-mavericks

I use GIT Tower to push to a remote repository and also use Terminal to connect to a few amazon AWS instances using key files from my Mac (OSX Mavericks)

For some reason, I've started receiving this error:

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key
```

I've tried running

```
ssh-add
```

I;ve tried resetting the permissions of the file, removed my known_hosts file, everything. Can't get my head round it, I haven't a clue why this has just started, but its very frustrating.

ANY feedback or help would be received with gratitude.

Thanks
Ste

Comment: I think this is probably better suited for the Super User Q&A site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the culprit is Tower v1.5.3. Had the same behaviour today on my Macs. Downgrading to Tower v1.5.2 helps. If the identity were added with v1.5.3 clear the identities in the SSH Agent (ssh-add -D) before connecting with Tower v1.5.2 again.

Note: You can use Tower v1.5.3, but then your SSH Key must have a passphrase to get this version of Tower to work.

Regards,
Andreas

Comment: thx for your hint! downgrading worked for me too. i wrote a little blog post about this problem as well: http://johannes.nagl.name/2014/Git-Tower-Error-Agent-admitted-failure-to-sign/

Answer (score 4):

Such kinds of errors may occur due to the incompatibility of `OpenSSH`. After generating the keys on your home directory, you can fix this error by simply loading your generated keys into your `SSH agent` with the following command:

```
 >$ ssh-add
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general problem with the Mac OS update 10.9.2 (see here for a general discussion, outside of Tower: [Git push keep getting permission denied after mac 10.9.2 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085581/git-push-keep-getting-permission-denied-after-mac-10-9-2-update))

As said before, running "ssh-add -D" on your command line, possibly combined with a restart of your Mac OS should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Tower 1.5.4 is out, with the correct bugfix:

changelog:
Simplify SSH Public Key management after Apple's security update in Mac OS 10.9.2

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this was to remove all identities. I ran the command

`ssh-add -D`

The prompt then returns: `All identities removed.`

I then logged in to my server via SSH and the message disappeared.