# Git push keep getting permission denied after mac 10.9.2 update

Tags: git, osx-mavericks

Wondering if anyone experiencing the same issue with OSX 10.9.2 Update. After installing that update, I couldn't do git push anymore, keep getting permission denied(public key).

Have tried to generate a new ssh pair, and reenter the new key to server, but still no luck.

Also tried to do it on another git hosting after inserting a new key, still doesnt work. So I guess its not a server problem, but a OSX 10.9.2 issue.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue too! All of my Git clients are coming back with the following error (when trying to push to BitBucket at least) since updating to 10.9.2: `Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.`

Comment: Yes, it's the same with mine..  I have tried to push to my own server, heroku, both dont work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with the Mavericks 10.9.2 update.  Anything using your ssh public key (ssh, git, svn, etc) will have a problem.  It seems that the ssh agent somehow forgot about your key.

Running `ssh-add` from the terminal fixed it for me. From these sources:

https://help.github.com/articles/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-appleosx-linux-bsd-agent-admitted-failuretosignusingkey/

Cheers

Comment: Was just about to post the same response. Did not know that SSH keys could become 'detached' like this. Great answer

Answer (score 0):

Add your ssh keys to your Keychain by running `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/<keyfile>`.

You can use `*` as key file to add all keys. This will ask for a passphrase for files which are not private keys. Just press enter for those files.

This adds keychain entries even for non-encrypted keys, i.e. keys that don't require a passphrase. After that it is not required to add the keys to the ssh-agent. So you can remove all keys from the agent by running `ssh-add -D` and public key authentication still works.